# Opera 11.50 Win32 flashes a white page on every page change

Tags: css, caching, rendering, opera

I'm having an issue with my site and Opera 11.50 browser on Win32. When I browse http://catza.net/ with Opera the page flashes white on every page change. Since the default palette is dark it is very annoying. It appears like Opera renders the reset stylesheet on each page change and displays the resulting white page just before rendering and displaying the actual dark page. Any idea why? The issue appears to be related to Opera since it doesn't occur with Chrome 12.0, Firefox 5.0, Internet Explorer 8.0 or Safari 5.1.

The site runs on a custom software and both Cache-Control and Expires are returned in every response. There are two simple stylesheets http://catza.net/style/reset/ and http://catza.net/style/dark/ that are loaded for every page.  The reset stylesheet by Yahoo gets 24 hours of lifetime while the dark stylesheet and the pages get 1 hour. With Firebug the caching headers look OK and and Expires matches the time set with Cache-Control. And when I check Opera's cache content I can see that both stylesheets are in cache: /style/reset/ 492 Bytes, /style/dark/ 1334 Bytes. The stylesheets are loaded at the very beginning of each page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en"><head>
<title>catza.net - the singing revolution of cat show photos </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/reset/">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/dark/">
...
```

Comment: I am not seeing your issue on Opera 11.5. What page are you clicking on?

Comment: For me it happens on each and every page change. Doesn't matter what page is clicked (as long as it is an internal link).

Comment: Can't see it either (opera 11.50). Maybe it's something in your opera - plugins or some user css. Have you tried clean install/other computer?

Comment: The reports that you're not having the issue are helpful since they help me to narrowing down the reason. I'll try a clean install next.

Comment: The clean install didn't fix the issue. At first after a clean install the white page is not flashed but at some point the issue returns and occurs again all the time on every page change. I have a theory that it starts to occur when the /style/dark/ stylesheet expires from cache. Next I'll test on another workstation.

Comment: The another workstation didn't reproduce the issue. I guess I'm out of ideas now.

Comment: Hi, @XDF. I'm having this issue on Opera 11.6 under Linux. Not only for catza, but for every other webpage. Every time I click on a link, this blank page flashes for about half a second just before rendering the content. Did you ever managed to solve this? Thanks

Comment: The issue still exists and I'm seeing it most of the time with my site and Opera browser. I'm now so used to it that it is hard to say if it happens also with other sites.